# Python GeeksForGeeks arrange array alternatively problem

Tags: python

I am attempting a Python practice problem on GeeksForGeeks, but my code raises IndexError every time.

The problem is as follows:

> Given a sorted array of positive integers `arr`, and an integer `n` which represents the length of `arr`, your task is to rearrange the array elements alternatively i.e first element should be max value, second should be min value, third should be second max, fourth should be second min and so on.
> Note: Modify the original array itself.

My code however raises `IndexError: list index out of range`

Here is my code:

```
def rearrange(arr, n):
        arr1,arr2 = sorted(arr[:(n//2)]), sorted(arr[(n//2):],reverse=True)
        arr.clear()
        for i in range(n):
            arr.append(arr2[0]); arr2.pop(0)
            arr.append(arr1[0]); arr1.pop(0)
```

Here is the error:

```
File &quot;/home/4c7d0350d40e21b84be527508f21cb47.py&quot;, line 9, in rearrange
    arr.append(arr2[0]); arr2.pop(0)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: You loop on `range(n)`. What is the length of `arr1` and `arr2`?

Comment: Also why are you always appending the first element and then popping it? Why not just appending the `i`th element?

Comment: Also why do you call `sorted`? The exercise says the input is already sorted...

Comment: Your edit would be better posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, both arr1 and arr2 are initialized with a length of `n//2`. In your for loop:

```py
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(arr2[0]); arr2.pop(0)
    arr.append(arr1[0]); arr1.pop(0)
```

You access the first element and remove the first element `n` times! This requires there to be `n` elements in `arr1` and `arr2`, but there are not this many. So, you keep trying to access the 0 index element of the array even after the array is empty, which causes this error.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this with try/except

Comment: You could post your final findings and solution - to the  question too. @433MEA

Comment: One ```hint``` is prob. looking into *deque*  It will allow to get the *first* as well as *last* item efficiently.

Comment: @DanielHao I wrote a better solution that is 30x faster. (code is in the post) However, the function does not modify the input array in-place. Could you take a look?

Comment: You forget to do ```return arr``` at the end.

Comment: Yes, that was purposeful. The original question asked to modify the input array in-place and not to return anything. However, when I print the input array it is unchanged. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** - this is not a direct answer to OP's question, since it's been addressed really clearly. But I'm tempting to share a reference implementation:
(which I think is more elegant - because it use the deque -operations at both end is O(1))

**Limitation** in this case, it assumes the array/list is even-sized, otherwise it won't work.  Thanks @Kelly's reminder.

```py
from collections import deque
L = deque(nums)
print(L)
#deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

while L:
    print(L.pop(), L.popleft())

    
9 1
8 2
7 3
6 4

# it will hit this error at the end:
#  IndexError: pop from an empty deque    # it's easier to convert it to a function and try-except ...      (leave as an exercise)
```

#### As @KellyBundy is interesting in the timing.

Thanks for the opportunity of *comparison*.
about the *complete* code, here it goes:

```py
from collections import deque

def rearr(A, n):
    dq = deque(A)
    A[:] = list()

    while dq:
        A.append(dq.pop())
        A.append(dq.popleft())

    return A

# sample 
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(rearr(A, 10))                   # would like to find out the running time...
```

#### Updates - final conclusion.

Per @Kelly quick timing testing proves that *slicing* is faster than the *deque* because the latter involved expensive function calls.  Thanks!

```py
from timeit import timeit
from collections import deque

def Deque(A):
    n = len(A)
    dq = deque(A)
    A[:] = list()
    while dq:
        A.append(dq.pop())
        A.append(dq.popleft())

def Slice(a):
  n = len(a)
  c = n // 2
  b = n - c
  a[::2], a[1::2] = a[:~b:-1], a[:c]

funcs = Deque, Slice

for n in range(0, 11, 2):
  for f in funcs:
    a = list(range(n))
    f(a)
    print(a, f.__name__)

for _ in range(3):
  print()
  for func in funcs:
    xss = [list(range(n)) for n in range(1000, 1008, 2)]
    t = timeit(lambda: [func(xs) for xs in xss], number=1)
    print(t * 1e6, func.__name__)
```

Output:

```
] Deque
[] Slice
[1, 0] Deque
[1, 0] Slice
[3, 0, 2, 1] Deque
[3, 0, 2, 1] Slice
[5, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2] Deque
[5, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2] Slice
[7, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3] Deque
[7, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3] Slice
[9, 0, 8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4] Deque
[9, 0, 8, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4] Slice

458.1600078381598 Deque
27.825008146464825 Slice

448.2280055526644 Deque
25.852001272141933 Slice

446.4329977054149 Deque
26.448993594385684 Slice
```

Comment: It's super important to solve the problem using the *right* Data Structure. Not only save time (interview/real life project) also more *performant*.

Comment: If you want it *really* performant, you don't use a deque but assign slices.

Comment: I'd timeit them if you finished your solution.

Comment: Crashes for odd lengths.

Comment: Newest edit looks like you don't intend to make your "reference implementation" work for all cases after all, so I reduced my benchmark to only test even lengths. For lengths around 1000 elements, slicing appears to be about 17 times faster:

Comment: [benchmark](https://tio.run/##dVFBboMwELzzij2aihBIpCpCyiFSf9AjQsjYprFkbMc4anrp1@naDkobqVzY2dmdmQX75c9G7w/WLcvozAReTkJ6kJM1zt9RFhlmlBLMS6PnlebichVZxsUIb6Ekp7zJAB8NR1BCI46QXxDz@0TsnNqmCzNy9iR1Ps9SCZxMAnGmpNYKzQm/lNZYkuf/UUqMPtAxybuSTBAak6w5aFhlCDRst7BDMESwAYY1bZtm1xX4rkOBDHa@h2ZTx2bDuiwbr5rNyMQ7i2SCXeNQRWpwVH8IUhVQ1wXsonfgxsDF1XQWXW9O8/p@0pgCAlgntSe0gLHse00n0fd5cukfLvson0bz1Qg9nrxuc8jb/rWDp8R1VYXQVXUIsbu46HEt/Xii6DRw2kAbdMltTvu3OQigPn4efZ0G4Y717/weXqAWr0VM8zhkWX4A)

Answer (score -4):

An index out of range means you are trying to access an item in your list at an index that does not exist.